# Is it possible to transcript a Twilio call "as you speak"?

Tags: ios, text, twilio, speech, transcription

Does anyone knows if it is possible by Twilio to create multiple audio records during a call based on a kind of audio flag or pattern, like silence for example. So that you could fire a callback on the end of each portion of speech to generate text during the call.

thank...

Answer (score 4):

Twilio Evangelist here.

So, you could use the `timeout` attribute on the [`<Record>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) to get short 'bursts' of spoken text, but this may mean you time out while the caller is speaking a word. So you would only get half of it! This may make it difficult to decipher what is being said, and I would personally not use this approach.

You can end recording on a key-press (a DTMF tone) with the `finishOnKey` attribute, which may help your needs.

You cannot currently get a live, or near realtime transcription. You will receive the transcription very quickly, but we only support the timeout and key presses to end a recording and begin transcription.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.  I have the following scenario... The Caller call a telephone number. The Call receiver answer the call and hear a message. The Call Receiver say something that be recorded and press * when he is finished with what he has to say. Is it possible to get the * from the person who receive the call so that I know when he is done with the message?

Comment: Ah, yes. There is a finishOnKey attribute in the <Record> verb that you can use to end a recording. Then Twilio submits to the action URL you specify. But the transcription will be a separate request a few seconds later... http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record

Answer (score 0):

To get live transcription with Twilio, you would need to use a 3rd party Speech To Text with [Twilio Media Streams](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/media-streams) that also supports a streaming/infinite speech to text recognition, like [Google Cloud Speech To Text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/samples/speech-transcribe-infinite-streaming).  Unfortunately I don't think there is a native Twilio verb or action that does live speech to text/live transcription.  Maybe you could run something on iOS, but I think having a backend server handle this is probably better and more scaleable in the future.

At a high level you need to do the following:

- Create a WebSocket endpoint to ingest Twilio Media Streams for incoming audio byte payloads.  These payloads are the base 64 encoding of speech over the telephone
- Send the media stream to a 3rd party speech to text provider, like Google Cloud
- Publish the transcription results to the end user (e.g. polling through an API or ideally a real time connection like another WebSocket).

Twilio themselves has created several different guides on how to do this:

- [Live Twilio transcription with Python](https://www.twilio.com/blog/transcribe-phone-calls-text-real-time-twilio-vosk)
- [Live Twilio transcription with Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/live-transcribing-phone-calls-using-twilio-media-streams-and-google-speech-text)
- [Live Twilio transcription with Spring Boot](https://www.twilio.com/blog/transcribe-phone-calls-twilio-media-streams-java-websockets-spring-boot)

I spent sometime familiarizing myself with these guides and made a similar [live transcription guide in Java using Dropwizard framework](https://www.sethmachine.io/2023/11/17/live-transcription-with-twilio-and-google/) as well (written by myself)

These approaches will work for proof-of-concepts but do not cover areas related to security or scaling of the audio stream processing.